# Opencv c++ image export to c#

Tags: c++, opencv, unity-game-engine, marshalling

im trying to write my own c++ plugin to use it in Unity3d. After I finished with frame processing I want to export it to Unity and assign to Texture2d, but I'm gettin a red questionmark texture and data passed to c# looks like : "���������������"

c++ DLL code:

```
extern "C" int EXPORT_API GetJpeg(unsigned char* *data, int* size)

cv::Mat myMat(frame);

std::vector<int> p;
p.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY);
p.push_back(10);
std::vector<unsigned char> buf;

cv::imencode(".jpg", myMat, buf, p);

*data = &buf.front();
*size = buf.size();

p.clear();
myMat.release();

if (buf.size() > 0)
{
    return 1;
}

return 0;
```

DLL import

```
[DllImport("OpenCVPlugin")]
static extern int GetJpeg(out IntPtr data, out int size);
```

Update function

```
if(capture < 1)
    {
        capture = StartCapture(camIndx);
        camIndx++;
    }

    process = ProcessFrame();

    int hr = 0;
    IntPtr frameData = IntPtr.Zero;
    int gSize = 0;

    hr = GetJpeg(out frameData, out gSize);
    byte[] arr = new byte[gSize];

    if(arr != null && gSize > 0)
    {
        Marshal.Copy(frameData, arr, 0, gSize);

        tex = new Texture2D(400,400);
        tex.LoadImage(arr);

        DisplayPlane.renderer.material.mainTexture = tex;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: Qbul3kz, have you had any progress in this question ?

Comment: Please if you solved your problem post the correct answer. I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that is going wrong is that 'buf' in GetJPEG is destroyed when GetJPEG returns, hence you're returning a pointer to freed memory.

You could use a global buffer in GetJPEG, or explicitly pass in a buffer.